# Firestore: update document where field value is null

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a list of unique codes, and users can request one, that must become unavailable for subsequent request.

So I need to update a document field on a single document ( without knowing it's id ) based on a document field value:

```
update <code_document> set <user_field> = <userID> where <user_field> = null limit 1
```

I can use a query like

```
Query query = ref.limit( 1 ).whereEqualTo( "user", null );
```

to get the document I want to update, and run the update after, but I need to guarantee that this runs only once and two users can't get assigned the same code.

**So the questions are:**
1. can i run a update with a *query* as a *where clause*

or
2. can i run a query inside a transaction to get a document reference, use that reference to update the document and then commit the transaction

Comment: Asking something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48284184/save-id-to-firestore-document
What I think is that even if you can do that (couldn't find the way yet), you will have to check the ddbb always twice: once asking for the reference and another one for the update. This is not a problem if you are a premium user but for free ones (like me) you have a maximum of ddbb checks and this reduces it to 50%